# Is there anyway to have Outlook calendar synced with a distribution list

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

I have a recurring calendar where the invite list is a distribution list.  The issue is that outlook seems to "resolve" the distribution list at that point in time and sends out the invite.

What I would like, is for the calendar to be in sync with the distribution list.  For example, if a week later, someone was added to the distribution list, they should automatically get an invite.

Is this possible as I always keep resending out this invite as people are added and deleted to make sure everyone has the invite and its quite annoying.

Comment: What version of Exchange please? What versions of Outlook (this one probably does not matter, but still good to have, in case)? Do you have any idea what the Server OS is for your domain controller? This can be done but I need more info to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done if you're using local Outlook distribution list (contact group) because Outlook replaces it with its members as soos as you press Send button on your Meeting.
I suggest you to use Exchange Server's distribution list for that.